# how can I upload multiple images from HTML to nodejs, rename it and save it in my directory

Tags: html, node.js

I am new in nodejs. How can I update multiple images from HTML to node js and rename it differently and save it to my directory Or is there another solution?

I have tried `multer` and those file can't rename with different names.

```
<form method="post" id='picForm' enctype="multipart/form-data" action='/test.html'>
  <input id="imgInpZero" type="file" name="avatar"/>
  <input id="imgInpOne" type="file" name="avatar"/>
  <button type="submit">提交</button>
</form>
```

My node js code:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'image')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "123.jpg");
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

app.post("/test.html", upload.array('avatar'), function(req, res, next) {});
```

I hope the two images have different names.

Comment: If you hard-code the name of the image ("123.jpg"), all images you upload would have the same name. In the worst case, last picture uploaded would be the only one saved, cause if you use the same folder with same name, all images would be overwritten...if you want to rename them, you can add an input field in the form and pass it in the function

Comment: I think the only missing part here is changing the names dynamically. Just add a global variable right before declaring `storage`. Call it `counter` or something like this. Then change `"123.jpg"` to something like `"image" + counter + ".jpg"`

Comment: I know I need to name the picture different, but I don't know how to write it. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the js code only. Here it is.

```js
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var img=0;
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'image')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    img+=1;
    var name='img'+ img + path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, name);
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

app.post("/test.html", upload.array('avatar'), function(req, res, next) {});
```

Just install path for the image extension. `npm install path`